# AndroidStudio still thinks the id of a drawable is seized by a missing resource

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-drawable, android-resources

I am testing an Android app with item-list->item-detail activity-fragment structure.

I get this kind of error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.text.style.DynamicDrawableSpan.getSize(DynamicDrawableSpan.java:81)
at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:207)
at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:281)
at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:284)
at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:170)
at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:6134)
at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:6032)
at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6389)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1502)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:556)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:95)
at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1556)
at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:803)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1352)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(Activi
```

It is originated in unknown place but it is related to a drawable.

```
span = new ImageSpan(activity, R.drawable.suitable_id);
```

The drawable was created from a svg file by means of new vector asset automatic import.

Before correctly importing it that way, I wrongly created a resource with a svg element inside a selector element. The id of the element was on the selector (suitable_id).

After the importing with vector asset I did not realize that the id was still recognized by the compiler, although it had not been assigned to the new resource.

So it gave the above null pointer error.

Now the id is on the vector element, it is the legitimate element (it has a path inside that reproduces the svg outline indeed), unless the id goes on the path element.

I cleaned the project and made it, but the resource still is not updated, I think it is trying to load the old missing resource. No files are present on the project, that I can see, corresponding to the old wrong resource.

What do I have to do now?

Comment: Try File -> Invalidate caches and restart

Comment: @Joe I performed what you suggested but the span is still null.

Comment: What happened when you tried to load the drawable yourself directly; i.e., `getDrawable(R.drawable.suitable_id)`? I just checked `ImageSpan`'s source again, and I mis-remembered, it seems. It actually swallows everything, not just `Resources$NotFoundException`, so it could be something else.

Comment: @Mike M. I also changed the suitable_id into new_id and renamed (refactored) the resources but I get the same error. Excuse me, which object I have to call the getDrawable() method on? (span is null after creating the new ImageSpan from the resource)

Comment: You can do `activity.getDrawable(R.drawable.suitable_id)` in the same location you're creating that `ImageSpan`.

Comment: @Mike M. the drawable (checked in a fragment, not activity) is android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable@6174ddf, and I was wrong the span is not null, it is android.text.style.ImageSpan@b204a2c but the getDrawable() method called on it yields a null value. Note that AndroidStudio shows me the correct thumbnail of the drawable on the left of instruction lines.

Comment: Hmm, well, that means the drawable's good. About the only thing left is `activity` being null, if that's that exact code you've got.

Comment: @Mike M. Drawable dr=this.getActivity().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_icon); yields the drawable correctly. It is span.getDrawable() that does not work.

Comment: Right. I'm saying that `activity` is null when you do `new ImageSpan(activity, ...)`.

Comment: @Mike M. You got it, thank you. It's strange that no error was issued there but whatever.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, that's bad design. I don't know why they don't throw right away. That's a really non-obvious Exception, there, 'cause if you'd gotten the `NullPointerException` message, it would've read `Attempt to invoke virtual method '...Rect ...Drawable.getBounds()' on a null object reference`, which absolutely does not immediately suggest the `Context` being null. Anyhoo, glad we finally got it figured out. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Invalidate caches and restart instead of rebuild